# Error on after cmommand biogeme = bio.BIOGEME(database,logprob)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to estimate a logit model on the choice between an electric and a gasoline car.

When I run the command
`biogeme  = bio.BIOGEME(database,logprob)`

I get the error attached in the image below:

[image]

I tried everything I knew from disinstalling anaconda and biogeme and notebook and nothing works.

I would be very thankful if you could please help me. I have no clue.

Comment: This is just part of the error.  I am not able to past a second image

Comment: You should copy the text of the error message, not an image of it. It would fit in one post and be searchable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first part of the error:

[image]